# What is the best way to send a SOAP request in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, soap

I want to send a SOAP request to a server that requires authentication. I've tried doing some of the methods in the HTTP:NET documentation but basic auth won't work. What would be the best way to contact this server with a user agent? I usually always get a connection time out error (500).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Savonrb](https://github.com/savonrb/savon) gem will be helpful for you in this case.

It is a ruby SOAP client to make SOAP communications easier. Also, check out this Railscasts [episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/290-soap-with-savon) to get started.